# Checking rtp stream audio quality

Tags: networking, voip, wireshark, audio, tshark

We are working in a test environment and need to monitor the audio quality of an rtp stream that is being captured using [tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html).

Right now we are able to capture the audio and access the file through [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), but we would like to find a way to save the audio to a .wav file (or similar) via the command line.

Does anyone know of a tool that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small tool called pcaputil - it is part of the [pjsip project](http://www.pjsip.org). It should be able to decode pcap files with RTP (G.711, G.722, speex and other codecs are supported) into wav files.

Compile pjsip and find pcaputil inside `pjsip-apps/bin/samples/[architecture]/`.